# Django Logger with User info

Tags: django, formatting, settings

I'm just curious. Is it possible to put `User` info within the `formatters` info in `LOGGING` config in `setting.py`?

Right now I just put that info in the message to log but maybe there's a way to set it in `formatters` argument.

This is my `LOGGING` configuration right now:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(funcName)s] %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': BASE_DIR + '/logs/uca_{:%d_%m_%Y}.log'.format(time.now()),
            'formatter': 'simple'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'ucalog': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't seen anything similar in django's documentation and I think it would be usefull to get records of WHO did WHAT.

Comment: I face the similar problem..Were you able to add username into logs?

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(funcName)s] - %(username)s: %(message)s'

logging.basicConfig(format=format)
logger.info(message, extra={'username' : request.user.username})
```