# How to control request object in logging handler

Tags: python, django

Hi im making a logging module in django

i want to save all of the user activity in `class Log` model

here is Log model

```
class Log(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("user")
    ip_address = models.Charfield()
    visited_view = models.Charfield()
```

for example, when user(testman) visit PostCreateView Log object will create
`("testman", '[user_ip_address]', 'visited_view')`

here is my `settings.py`

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'handlers': {
    'db_logger': {
        'class': 'myapp.utils.logging.LogHandler',
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'request': {
        'handlers': ['db_logger'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    }
},
}
```

db_logger will use My Custom LogHandler

```
from myapp.models import Log


class LogHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        if record.name.split('.')[0]=='request':
            user = recored.request.user ## This is what i want :)
            Log.objects.create()
```

and In CreateView insert logging command

```
my_logger = logging.getLogger('db_logger')

class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    def get_context_data(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        my_logger.warning('test')
```

but I have big problem now because `logging.Handler` is python lib not django So i can't control request in `LogHandler` :(

How can i control request object in Handler? thank you :)

Comment: Have a look over this answer, and consider how keywords in the format strings get populated from the extra param. You should be able to do something like this in your own logger; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534211/django-logger-with-user-info

Comment: @markwalker_ thank you but even though i use extra i can't still control request object and I want save user foreignkey object in Log Table so i need user object